# PHP code to block out any code in the page

Tags: php, html

I currently have the following code on my page.

```
<?php 
    if($result["r_approved"] == "APPROVED"){
echo "<!--";
} 
?>
<div class="main">
    <div class="main-sub">
<?php include('http://www.contractorsintelligence.com/contractors-license/includes-page-elements/navigation1.php'); ?>
<div id="mid-top"><img src="https://www.contractorsintelligence.com/images/shadowbg-top.png" width="990" height="20" alt="Top Spacer"/></div>
            <div id="mid_shdw">
    <?php
    if($result["r_approved"] == "APPROVED"){
echo "-->";
} 
?>
```

With this code, I'm trying to block/ignore a block of code with `<!--` and `-->`, but it does not want to ignore php code.  How would I use PHP to block out an entire section of the code?  I would really appreciate if you would use my current "if" statement variables.

Comment: can you just comment out the code you don't want to execute?

Comment: Can you be more clear on what code exactly you are trying to ignore? Are you trying to comment the PHP out with `<!--`?

Comment: PHP couldn't care less about HTML comments. If you want to disable PHP code, then you need to use PHP comments: `#` or `/* ... */` or `//`

Comment: Why would you comment it out instead of just not sending it at all?

Comment: So this was basically not knowing how to properly use IF statements?

Answer (score 6):

Why not this:

```
<?php
if($result["r_approved"] != "APPROVED"){
?>
<div class="main">
    <div class="main-sub">
<?php include('http://www.contractorsintelligence.com/contractors-license/includes-page-elements/navigation1.php'); ?>
<div id="mid-top"><img src="https://www.contractorsintelligence.com/images/shadowbg-top.png" width="990" height="20" alt="Top Spacer"/></div>
            <div id="mid_shdw">
<?php
}
?>
```

Comment: Or even better: `<?php if (...): ?>` ... `<?php endif; ?>`. Those lonely closing braces really hurt readability in these situations.

Comment: Yes, didn't feel like changing more code than needed, especially if they don't use that syntax in other code.  Consistency.

Answer (score 1):

Put the code inside the if. Please note that I also changed the if to a "does not equal"

```
<?php if($result["r_approved"] !== "APPROVED"): ?>
    <div class="main">
        ...
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

I used the alternative syntax for readability reasons as I think it looks much cleaner than with the brackets if you mix PHP with HTML.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say a much cleaner way to do this would be to use the alternative syntax for the if statement. This removes the obfuscation caused by printing comments from php. In your case, that would be:

```
<?php if(! $result["r_approved"] == "APPROVED"):?>
<div class="main">
    <div class="main-sub">
<?php include('http://www.contractorsintelligence.com/contractors-license/includes-page-elements/navigation1.php'); ?>
<div id="mid-top"><img src="https://www.contractorsintelligence.com/images/shadowbg-top.png" width="990" height="20" alt="Top Spacer"/></div>
            <div id="mid_shdw">
    <?php endif; ?>
```

You can read more on the alternative syntax [here](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php).